# How to replace string (1) with 1 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, replace

I have 1000 file names in my table.

My files' names are `test%20(1).jpg, test%20(2).jpg....test%20(1000).jpg`.

I want to replace files' names to `test1.jpg, test2.jpg ... test1000.jpg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try **[REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)** function

```
select replace(replace(col,'%20(',''),')','')
from t
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1e00/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
update mytable t1, (SELECT @rank:=0) t2
set myname = concat('test',@rank:=@rank+1,'.jpg');
```

or if applicable to retain order (in 2 queries):

```
SET @rank:= 0;
UPDATE mytable
SET myname = concat('test',@rank:=@rank+1,'.jpg')
ORDER By myname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `REPLACE` twice here

```
UPDATE tableName
SET name = REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '%20(', ''), ')','')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25e1c/1)
- [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)